# Добавление данных в RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, xml, adapter

Доброй ночи. Модернизирую следующий фрагмент моего проекта. На моём `activity_xxx` собрал вот такое отображение объектов, где `item n++` - некие случайные заголовки, обёрнутые в `cardview` и пока что стандартную картинку в `imageView`.

[image: <Пришли некие данные по сети...>]

Исходный же ход пока что остается прежним, и мне требуется вытащить заголовки и вставить на места item'ов:

```
for (int i = 0; i < stringObjectsDetails.length; i++) {
    stringObjectsDetails[i] = objectsDetails.get(i).getTitle();
}

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_objects);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
        R.layout.object_item, stringObjectsDetails);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Получив информацию, моя прога собирала её в некий `ListView`. Вопрос в правильном переводе моего адаптера типа `Array` в более подходящий для компонента, который не является листом. Прилагаю исходный код:

```
activity_xxx.xml (1)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list_objects_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:listitem="@layout/object_item"/>
</FrameLayout>



object_item.xml (2)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:id="@+id/object_logo"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/object_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="8dp"
            tools:text="@string/title_object_string"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />
    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

P.s. Огромная просьба не советовать мне пользоваться гуглом. Я дейсвительно почитал даже зарубежный стековерфлоу и кое-что попробовал, но у меня здесь особая как мне кажется ситуация, и я до сих пор нахожусь в поисках универсального либо какого-то гибкого решения.

UPD:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы хотите вместо ListView использовать RecyclerView, но не знаете как?

Comment: @pavlofff, да. Всё что требуется - засунуть в него данные с заголовками из массива.

Comment: RecyclerView использует свой RecyclerView.Adapter и ему не подойдёт ArrayAdapter. Перепишите свой адаптер под RecyclerView

Comment: @EgorD, спасибо! Дам ответ на свой же вопрос, если у меня получится.